# AFNetworking 2.0 & Background Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to load an image that will be displayed at the background of my app by using *AFNetworking*. The problem comes when the `viewDidLoad` calls to load the image, the *AFNetworking* is not done loading the data, so it doesn't display.

Here my Code.

**AFNetworking**:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    // 3
    NSDictionary *user = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

    NSString *backurlJSON=[user valueForKeyPath:@"back_url"][0];
    NSLog(@"Background from Start: %@",backurlJSON);

    if(![backurlJSON isEqualToString:@""]){

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mydomain.com/images/%@", backurlJSON]];
         NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url ];
         imgBack = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data ];

        backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: imgBack];
```

So in the `viewDidLoad` I have the subview `UIImageView` loading an image, in case there is no image to load, that I will like to overwrite with the one coming from the *AFNetworking*.

**ViewDidLoad**:

```
background = [UIImage imageNamed: @"2.png"];
backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: background];
backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(-10, -10, 340, 588);
backgroundView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code, you are using AFNetworking to download a JSON file with the 'back_url', then you are downloading the image in the main thread, instead of this code:

```
if(![backurlJSON isEqualToString:@""]){

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mydomain.com/images/%@", backurlJSON]];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url ];
    imgBack = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data ];

    backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: imgBack];
}
```

You can use something like:

```
    NSString *backurlJSON=[user valueForKeyPath:@"back_url"][0];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mydomain.com/images/%@", backurlJSON]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


    AFHTTPRequestOperation *postOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    postOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
    [postOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        backgroundView.image = responseObject;

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're overwriting your UIImageView and never adding it back to the view hierarchy. Try changing the image property of your image view instead of creating a new one:

```
[backgroundView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:imgBack waitUntilDone:NO];
```

instead of

```
backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: imgBack];
```

Comment: I personally prefer `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ /* do stuff on main thread */ });` to `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`. There's nothing inherently wrong with your way (which is/was the norm), except  that it only works in cases where you only have one operation to perform and no more than one parameter needed for it.